# Explaining MENSA's IQ Problem on Alien Fingers

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There is one probably quite well-known IQ puzzle below from Mensa:

> There are a number of aliens in a room. Each alien has more than one finger on each hand. All aliens have the same number of fingers as each other. All aliens have a different number of fingers on each hand. If you knew the total number of fingers in the room you would know how many aliens were in the room. There are between $200$ and $300$ alien fingers in the room. How many aliens are in the room?
>
> --- Puzzle courtesy of MENSA.

I know the answer is $17$, the explanation is that the number of fingers is the square of a prime, the only squares between $200$ and $300$ are $15^2$, $16^2$ and $17^2$, and only $17^2$ is the square of a prime, so there are $17$ aliens in the room.

It is a beautiful puzzle, but I still don't get two of the parts where it says:

1. "*Each alien has more than one finger on each hand*" - This means that the option for an alien having $1$ hand with $1$ finger and the other with $16$ fingers is not possible, thus the number of aliens will be less than $17$.
2. "*All aliens have a different number of fingers on each hand*" - This means that if there is one alien having, say, $6$ fingers on the left hand and $11$ on the right hand, and another alien having $11$ on the left hand and $6$ fingers on the right hand, the statement would be violated, therefore the number of aliens will be much smaller than $17$.
3. Essentially, the only possible combinations of number of fingers is $$(2,15)\; (3,14)\; (4,13)\; (5,12)\; (6,11)\; (7,10)\; (8,9)\,,$$ so $17$ is not actually a correct answer.

Is there anything I have missed or is it that the wording of the puzzle is incomplete?

Comment: How do we know that the aliens have two hands each, or even that they all have the same number of hands?

Comment: This is a terrible puzzle. The language is very ambiguous - it isn't just you, OP.

Comment: Given that there are $289$ fingers, how do you know that there are $17$ aliens? Why couldn't it be just one alien with $289$ fingers?

Comment: Good observation @bof, the puzzle was usually given as multiple choices and 1 was not included. I guess if this is not a multiple-choice, the puzzle would state that there are more than 1 alien in the room.

Comment: Maybe "All aliens have a different number of fingers on each hand" just means no alien has the same number of fingers on his right hand as he has on his left hand.

Comment: "If you knew the total number of fingers..." is a key information. It means that there is a unique number of fingers between $200$ and $300$ such that with that many fingers, the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is the number of aliens who all have hands with a, b, c, d fingers on multiple hands) then total number of fingers is $T = n(a+b+c+d$....).  As we can deduce from this the number of aliens and the answer is unique then the factorization of T must be unique into two primes.  If $n$ and $(a+b+c+d...)$ are different primes this would lead to two answers for the number of aliens therefore $n = a+b+c$....  So $T=n^2$ where $n$ is prime.  If $200 < T < 300$ then $n=17$.

Comment: Couldn't it also be that T is prime, implying n=1?

Comment: Except that we know that all aliens have the same number of fingers as each other implying n>1.